# CoffeeScript 1.9.0 changes to variable names

Tags: coffeescript

In the [CoffeeScript 1.9.0 ChangeLog](http://coffeescript.org/#changelog), I read:

> Changed strategy for the generation of internal compiler variable names. Note that this means that `@example` function parameters are no longer available as naked `example` variables within the function body.

I don't quite understand what this means for me as a user. Is this somehow an incompatible change? Can I safely upgrade to version 1.9.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. Yes, this change is incompatible. If you had written tests, you could check if it affects you. Take this little piece of code:

```
example = "new"
obj = method: (@example) -> console.log(example)
obj.method "old"
```

In 1.8 this would print `old`. In the new version, this prints `new`.

In the older version, `@example` would be translated to `example` in the method parameters. So you're accessing `obj.method`'s function parameter in the old version.
In the new version you're accessing the `example` variable of the outer scope. `a.example` still gets set to `"old"` in both cases.

Here you can see the difference in the generated JS code:

```
-// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.7.1
+// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.9.0
 (function() {
   var example, obj;

   example = "new";

   obj = {
-    method: function(example) {
-      this.example = example;
+    method: function(_at_example) {
+      this.example = _at_example;
       return console.log(example);
     }
   };

   obj.method("old");

 }).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

See Patrick J. S.’ answer for what the change means.

See [How do I find cases of CoffeeScript 1.9.0 breaking change in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187150/how-do-i-find-cases-of-coffeescript-1-9-0-breaking-change-in-my-code/) for how to know if you can upgrade safely, and what you need to do if not.