# Why @ replaced with _at_? (CoffeeScript)

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I have a problem with classes in Angular.
When i trying to create some class for controller, i see this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: _at_$scopeProvider <- _at_$scope <- MainController
```

Code of Class:

```js
class MainController
    constructor: (@$scope, @$log) ->
        @timestamp = Date.now() - 900000

angular
    .module 'app'
    .controller 'MainController', MainController
```

As a result i have this:

```
(function() {
  var MainController;

  MainController = (function() {
    function MainController(_at_$scope, _at_$log) {
      this.$scope = _at_$scope;
      this.$log = _at_$log;
      this.timestamp = Date.now() - 900000;
    }

    return MainController;

  })();

  angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);

}).call(this);
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You updated to coffee version 1.9. There is an incompatible change in the naming of property arguments. See my answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347290/coffeescript-1-9-0-changes-to-variable-names/28348524), it affects you. Since you are using angular, you can use the array notation for injection. If you want to minify/uglify your code, this is the only way to get the injection right anyway, thus I'd recommend to always do it like that.

Either like this:

```
class MainController
    constructor: (@$scope, @$log) ->
        @timestamp = Date.now() - 900000

angular
    .module 'app'
    .controller 'MainController', ['$scope', '$log', MainController]
```

or like this:

```
MainCtrlWithInjects = ['$scope', '$log', 
    class MainController
    constructor: (@$scope, @$log) ->
        @timestamp = Date.now() - 900000
     ]

angular
    .module 'app'
    .controller 'MainController', MainCtrlWithInjects
```